# if (true || true || false) statement is true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I have this bit of code to protect my page from being iframed.

```
window.onload = function(){
 try
  {
   if (window.parent && window.parent.location.hostname !== "app.herokuapp.com"){
      throw new Error();
   }
   catch (e){
   //do something
   }
  }
```

It works perfectly fine until I try to add more values to compare the hostname with. I want to add my custom domain name. I tried this:

```
window.onload = function(){
 try
  {
   if (window.parent && (window.parent.location.hostname !=="app.herokuapp.com" 
   || window.parent.location.hostname !== "www.app.com"
   || window.parent.location.hostname !== "localhost")){
      throw new Error();
   }
   catch (e){
   //do something
   }
  }
```

This always returns true and therefore throws an error.  How can I make this work? Unless the hostname matches these strings, I want to throw an error and it throws an error no matter what. I am new at this and would love some help! Thanks.

Ps. I added "localhost" because I want to be able to test it locally before pushing to heroku.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`||` returns evaluates to `true` if *any* of the operands evaluate to `true`. Perhaps you meant to use `&&` instead:

```
if (window.parent 
    && window.parent.location.hostname !== "app.herokuapp.com" 
    && window.parent.location.hostname !== "www.app.com"
    && window.parent.location.hostname !== "localhost")
```

Or by [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if (window.parent 
    && !(window.parent.location.hostname === "app.herokuapp.com" 
         || window.parent.location.hostname === "www.app.com"
         || window.parent.location.hostname === "localhost"))
```

This will evaluate to `true` if *all* of the operands evaluate to `true`.

**Further Reading**

- [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's already a pretty complete answer I would suggest a different approach. When you have long  statements like that, I find that working with higher-order functions is easier to read. Think of your condition this way: "Check if the hostname doesn't match any of the given strings". That's how I would like to read the code, everything else is boilerplate:

```
function not(y) {
  return function(x) {
    return x !== y;
  };
}

var hosts = ['app.herokuapp.com','www.app.com','localhost'];
var parent = window.parent;

if (parent && hosts.some(not(parent.location.hostName))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I started thinking that way and wasn't sure how to accomplish it. Thank you. It does look cleaner.